# GData API Calendar ObjC documentation

Tags: objective-c, api, calendar, gdata

Can't find any documentation for GData API objective-C. Just introduction and example-code.

Where can I find detail description of methods and structures for this API?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/wiki/GDataObjCIntroduction) you can find the requirements and an introduction to how to use **GDATA for iphone**

Comment: It's won't help. There is no any information about data format and etc. Only simple introduction as I wrote upper. But thanks a lot. any way.

Answer (score 0):

The Objective-C API classes are just documented by their header files. You can read the protocol documentation for each API on the web. The sample applications for each API show how to use them with the Objective-C library.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at this example for the Calendar API but it seems to use an old version of the library, the source code does not compile against [the latest version](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-gcal/).